# Symfony - uuid-doctrine - Return the UUID as a string from the query builder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, uuid

I use the `ramsey/uuid-doctrine` module to manage UUIDs.

I want to get the UUID as a string from the result of a query executed through the query builder.

I use the following code:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')           
    ->select('a.id AS id, at.name AS name')
    ...
```

The id field is the UUID, declared as follows into the entity file:

```
/**                                                                             
 * @ORM\Id                                                                      
 * @ORM\Column(type="uuid", unique=true)                                        
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")                                       
 * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidGenerator")           
 */                                                                             
private $id;
```

The query result returns the UUID as an object of type Uuid. Is there any way to get directly the UUID as a string from the query builder result ?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look here (DQL) : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#result-format .  To get raw data you could be querying with SQL as well.